# How to count how many times an imported MS-Build property was referenced (read) by a project?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-sdk

How to count how many times an imported MS-Build property was referenced (read) by a project ?

For example one of the files imported by the MS-Build Project defines a sensitive property `$(CipherNonce)` like this:

```xml
</Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
            <CipherNonce>314159</CipherNonce>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I would like to determine how many times the `$(CipherNonce)` property was read/used (referenced) by this MS-Build Project, which also imports dozens of `.targets` files.

At the moment I am using the `-preprocess[:filepath]` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019) to generate a single, aggregated project file, which I am searching for references to `$(CipherNonce)` with a regex - but that is such a hack and it misses the references to this property, which are made by the VS IDE.

I also looked at [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectproperty?view=msbuild-17-netcore) and [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.property?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) and [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.getproperty?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "references to this property" that "are made by the VS IDE".  Can you explain what that is or give an example?

Comment: `devenv.exe` parses the project (including all its imports) and reads these MS_Build properties and displays their values in its dialog boxes and property sheets and uses them in Intellisense and in paths to files.

Comment: If the point of the exercise is an assessment of exposure or risk, the Visual Studio IDE UI is interactive so the number of 'references' is indeterminate for general use. If the `CipherNonce` value is security sensitive and must be secret and/or access controlled then it shouldn't be in source code, which includes the project file.

Comment: Assessment of risk exposure is off-topic.  References made by the VS IDE are a minor issue.  Counting the references to a static property made by the MS-Build project is the major issue.  (even the ability to determine whether that count is more than zero would be significant).

Comment: Then 'find in files' for `$(CipherNonce)` will suffice.

Comment: That does not work in the general case because of indirect constructs such as this: `<PropsToProcess Include="@(PropNames)"> <Val>$(%(PropNames.Identity)) </Val> </PropsToProcess>` and the undetermined set of imported files which do not have to reside in the same directory - requiring recursive processing of the `<Import Project="path"/>` directives.

Comment: `CipherNonce` is a property which exists in your source code. You don't need to follow imports. Just search in the files in your source code. `PropsToProcess` and `PropNames` are also your source code. `PropsToProcess` and `PropNames` are ItemGroups, not Properties. If the value of the `CipherNonce` is used, it be as `$(CipherNonce)`. If there is an Item added to `PropNames` using the `CipherNonce` property it will presumably be something like `<PropNames Include="CipherNonce" PropValue="$(CipherNonce)" />`. (The `PropValue` metadata could be named something else.)

Comment: If it was all my code this would not be an issue. There are different teams who send in code and I have no control over their imports. Also, notice that even if `PropsToProcess` and `PropNames` are `ItemGroups`, the indirect construct `$(%(PropNames.Identity))` accesses the values of properties whose names are listed inside the `PropNames`. Of course there can be multiple property names inside the `PropNames` which causes this indirect construct to access multiple properties. (including e.g. `CipherNonce`)

Comment: I understand the problem now. It's an uncommon technique, in general at least, but I imagine there are code bases that use it extensively. Grepping for `$(%(` will show if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild currently doesn't track all property reads (just unassigned property reads and env var reads). That being said - if you'd need to track all property reads, you'd need to build your version of MSBuild and hook the read yourself ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/56087a97257fab6a67d110a7b2c4116f707325ee/src/Build/Evaluation/PropertyTrackingEvaluatorDataWrapper.cs#L158-L183))